# Camel cased CSS in Styled Components or Emotion for regular React?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I program mostly with React Native, whose *styled* properties inherit most of CSS syntax and are done with camel case, such as:

```
    //...
    <Component style={styles.container} />

    //... 


const styles = StyleSheet.Create({
  container: {

    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "white"
    //Etc...

  }
})
```

I can't seem to find good documentation in either library to see if this style is acceptable, and if so, how to implement it, in Styled-Components or Emotion for regular React?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With styled components, you use it just like normal `css`.

You can also see [a style cheat sheet](https://github.com/vhpoet/react-native-styling-cheat-sheet) for react native styles.

You can use inline styles for reactjs, it will have the similar sintax, but with a few different options, as you can see in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

e.g.

```
// camel case css
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

Please notice that **this is not recommended**, as they say in the docs:

> ... **using the style attribute as the primary means of styling elements is generally not recommended**. In most cases, `className` should be used to reference classes defined in an external CSS stylesheet. `style` is most often used in React applications to add dynamically-computed styles at render time

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there way, using either library or another one, that allows me to do it the "react native" way?

Comment: You want to use react native styles in reactjs ?

Comment: I'm just used to the styling way of react native, so not sure if it's possible to do it in React that way or with i.e. emotion / styled components

Comment: are you familiar with `styled-components`?

Comment: Yes I've used it before, and I know how to use styled etc and regular css. I'm just wondering if there is a method to use camel case like react native, which is what I'm used to.

Comment: @stephenlizcano you can use inline style, but you should use it only for dynamic styles. styled components or normal css would be much better